# Crash during device rotation on a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I've a custom image which I'm setting as badge on a view. On rotation I call a function to change the leading constraints for this image. Following code crashes when device is rotated.

What is the reason for this and how to fix it?

```
@IBOutlet weak var badgeLeadingConstraints: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
        // This is called during the animation
    }, completion: { context in
        self.updateBadgeConstraints()
    })
}

func updateBadgeConstraints() {
    // Crash on following line
    // Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    self.badgeLeadingConstraints.constant = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 4) + 34
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `badgeLeadingConstraints` is `nil`. Maybe, it's becoming `nil` after device rotation. Try to use size classes or just create a new constraint.

Comment: That's true, it becomes nil. I've added this constraints in storyboard. I would like to know why it becomes nil after device orientation?

Comment: @Davis Check debug info, I think AutoLayout engine is braking it  because it cannot satisfy this constraint. Can't say more without looking into code/storyboard.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Adding constraints manually doesn't help as the image itself becomes nil so I can't do anything on that image. I think this code executes when view is still in transition which is causing image to be nil along with constraints. Is the code above is correct to call the function after view has transitioned completely? Is there any other function which we can call after view has transitioned completely?